# How do I disable Stack Overflow text area keybindings?

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts, editor

Stack Overflow hijacks my native keybindings for editing text areas. This is really annoying, as keybindings like <kbd>C-h</kbd> (for backspace) and <kbd>C-b</kbd> (for backwards character) are etched into my muscle memory due to chronic Emacs usage. How do I stop the site from hijacking these keybinds?

Comment: See also [Please add a user preference to allow me to disable your fancy textarea and use a plain one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76581/163868).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to change Stack Overflow's keybindings you could edit text areas with an editor. This way you can choose an editor with keybindings that you prefer.

Text areas can be integrated with an editor of your choice via plugins such as the Firefox plugin [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/its-all-text/). With such a plugin you can effectively switch from editing in a text area to editing the same text in an editor. An example on how to use that plugin is found in [an answer to Emacs mode for Stack Overflow's markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386560/789593).

Comment: That linked question belongs here on Meta.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd That depends. The question is mostly about Emacs and as such it belongs on SO. A question "How do I use technology X to interact with SO" is primarily not about SO, which would make it most on topic on MSO, but primarily about the technology X which makes it fit for any site where technology X is on topic.